# Logistic function - Derivative missing ln(b)

Tags: calculus

I am a bit stuck in a specific step - I could read numerous posts on it but I can't figure out how to solve the following stage of the derivative process (first part of the logistic cost function):

$$\frac{∂}{∂θj}[log(hθ(xi))]=\frac{1}{hθ(xi)}*\frac{∂}{∂θj}hθ(xi)$$

The same applies for second part : $$\frac{∂}{∂θj}[log(1-hθ(xi))]=\frac{1}{1-hθ(xi)}*\frac{∂}{∂θj}1-hθ(xi)$$
If I am not  wrong, the rule for differentiating $$log_{(b)}(u)$$ (with u = sigmoid(z) which is a function) should be $$\frac{1}{u*ln(b)} * \frac{du}{dx}$$

Why do we have here only $$\frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{dx}$$ as if we were using $$ln(u)$$ instead of $$Log_{10}(u)$$

Why ln(b) is missing if we respect the rule above ?

thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "logistic cost function", the logarithm $\log$ means the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm). In other words, $\log(x)=\ln(x)$ in your context.

So for instance, by the chain rule, you have
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Why not using ln then.... It is logical to me now :)